# UIActivityViewController Gmail share extension duplicated body

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've seen some weird thing with the gmail share extension, like the body and the subject fields are empty if you want to share a content containing a & character.

It's possible to get it working with escaping the & character with `&amp;`, however this way the body in the message is duplicated (once the original, and once the escaped.

Do you guys know a workaround for this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I've found is to remove every special characters (I was able to replace & with 'and' - it was in text, not in link)